# Ubuntu 18.04 Thinkpad T460p w/ UltraDock 4k@60Hz Blank Screen

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, external-monitor, displayport, 4k-monitor

I have a thinkpad T460p running ubuntu 18.04 on an UltraDock connected by DisplayPort to a 4K monitor. The monitor will work most of the time at 4K @ 30Hz. Sometimes I get a flickering artifact at the top of the screen. If I try to switch to 4K @ 60Hz, the screen turns black and then goes into sleep mode even though the windowing system thinks it is working. Anyone have ideas on how to fix the blanking or at least the flickering?

I've double checked that my hardware can handle what I'm asking:

- Laptop specs: http://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad%20T460p/ThinkPad_T460p_Platform_Specifications.pdf
- Dock specs: http://s3.amazonaws.com/isby/lenovopartnernetwork.com/upload/4/docs/presentation-thinkpad-docking-solutions.pdf

I've tried updating the kernel to 4.18.2, but to no effect. I've checked `dmesg` and `syslog`, but there are no errors mentioned after switching to 60Hz other than mention of compressing the frame buffer.

I found a [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96828) that described similar problems from 2016, but it looks like those problems were resolved and I'm guessing merged into newer kernels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the monitor. There was a setting deep in the menus to switch the displayport protocol from 1.1 to 1.2. Once switched, the computer works perfectly at 60Hz.